# Python XOR Decryption Only Decrypting Half of RGB Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, encryption, rgb

I am trying to XOR decrypt an encrypted image in Python using a provided key. 
I have been able to decrypt half of the image, and I can't understand why the bottom half does not get decrypted as well.

```
key = np.load('key.npy')
secret = plt.imread('secret.bmp')

newArr = secret.copy()

for t, k in zip(secret, key):
    e = t^k
    newArr[t] = e

plt.imshow(newArr)
```

Is there something wrong with my loop that makes the decryption stop after only traversing half the image rows?

[image]

Comment: could you check the sizes of the image and the key?

Comment: The length of the key is 800 and the length of the image is 467.

Comment: How do you encrypted? the key size can encrypt only one row of the image! You should definitely post the encryption code, too.

Comment: I did not write the encryption code. My instructor encrypted the image.

Comment: Your image 800x467 right? and the key size is 800. I can guess that the key is repeated for every row of the image.

Comment: @codenoob What is the output of `print('key:', key.shape, 'secret:', secret.shape)`?

Answer (score 2):

You are writing to `newArr[t]` but `t` is the secret byte value not an index. You should replace the for loop entirely with a logical-xor on the contents of `secret` and `key` (assuming the key and the secret arrays/matrices are broadcastable to the same shape; read more about broadcasting [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html)):

```
key = np.load('key.npy')
secret = plt.imread('secret.bmp')

newArr = np.logical_xor(key, secret)
plt.imshow(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have `len(key) < len(secret)`.

Python's `zip` function will stop when it reaches the end of the shorter sequence, so if the key is too short, your problem will not decrypt the leftover data when it reaches the end of `key`.